# Re-arranging equation missing steps

Tags: algebra-precalculus

What are the steps to get from:

$Y(s)\left(10s^2+7s+2-\frac{(3s+2)^2}{7s^2+9s+7}\right)=F(s)$

to:

$G(s)=\frac{Y(s)}{F(s)}=\frac{(7s^2+9s+7)}{(10s^2+7s+2)(7s^2+9s+7)-(3s+2^2)}=\frac{7s^2+9s+7}{70s^4+139s^3+138s^2+55s+10}$

My first step is:

$\frac{Y(s)}{F(s)}=\frac{1}{10s^2+7s+2-\frac{(3s+2^2)}{7s^2+9s+7}}$

I'm not sure where to go from here...

Comment: Compare to: $\;\displaystyle \frac{1}{a-\frac{b}{c}}=\frac{1}{\frac{ac-b}{c}}=\frac{c}{ac-b}\,$.

Comment: It's a **complex fraction** (a fraction which contains so-called **minor** fractions in the numerator or denominator). One reduces a complex fraction to an ordinary fraction by simultaneously multiplying the numerator and the denominator by the least common denominator of the minor fractions. In this case it means multiplying the numerator and the denominator by $7s^2+9s+7$.

Answer (score 0):

$$Y(s)\left(10s^2+7s+2-\frac{(3s+2)^2}{7s^2+9s+7}\right)=F(s)$$

Remember, $\frac{a}{a}=1$, therefore multiplying and dividing $(10s^2+7s+2)$ will give it the same denominator as has $(3s+2)^2$, thus making it easy to work with:

$$Y(s)\left(
\frac{(10s^2+7s+2)(7s^2+9s+7)-(3s+2)^2}{7s^2+9s+7}
\right)=F(s)$$

Re-arrange to the desired form $\frac{Y(s)}{F(s)}$

$$\frac{Y(s)}{F(s)}=\left(
\frac{7s^2+9s+7}{(10s^2+7s+2)(7s^2+9s+7)-(3s+2)^2}
\right)$$

Expand the denominator, collect terms and then you should arrive at the result